# How can I filter a simple LINQ query and use it in a more complexe LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

i have this logic in one of my function but it does 3 roundtrips to the database. How can i convert the query to make only one query to the database?

```
var saisonTouristiqueId = 1;
var currentSaison = this.appContext.SaisonTouristiques.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SaisonTouristiqueId == saisonTouristiqueId);

var nextSaison = (from saison in this.appContext.SaisonTouristiques
                  where saison.DebutSaison > currentSaison.FinSaison
                  orderby saison.DebutSaison
                  select saison).FirstOrDefault();

if (nextSaison != null)
{
    var forfaits = from forfait in this.appContext.Forfaits
                   where forfait.ComposantForfaits.Any(x => x.SaisonTouristiqueId == nextSaison.SaisonTouristiqueId)
                   select forfait;

    return forfaits.ToList();
}
```

Comment: I think you can use join

Comment: @COLDTOLD I don't see how you could, given what he's doing.

Comment: Maybe cross join i did not realize his both queries are on one table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only use `FirstOrDefault` when in the subsequent query, to allow all of the execution to be deferred.

```
var saisonTouristiqueId = 1;
var currentSaison = this.appContext.SaisonTouristiques
    .Where(x => x.SaisonTouristiqueId == saisonTouristiqueId);

var nextSaison = from saison in this.appContext.SaisonTouristiques
                    where saison.DebutSaison > currentSaison.FirstOrDefault().FinSaison
                    orderby saison.DebutSaison
                    select saison;

var forfaits = from forfait in this.appContext.Forfaits
                where forfait.ComposantForfaits.Any(x => x.SaisonTouristiqueId == nextSaison.FirstOrDefault().SaisonTouristiqueId)
                select forfait;

return forfaits.ToList();
```